vee-validate select not updating another field based on selection
I have two Shadcn-vue select dropdowns in a form using Vee-Validate for validation. The first dropdown, manHoursSelect, allows the user to choose a preset value. Based on this selection, the second dropdown, manHours, should automatically update with a corresponding value (like "1.0" or "0.5").
While the correct values are submitted when the form is submitted, the second dropdown doesn’t visually update when the first one is changed. This means that although the form logic works in the backend, the user interface doesn’t reflect the expected value in the second dropdown when they make a selection in the first.
I have recreated what I wanted in basic HTML and it works correctly.
<template>
    <form @submit="onSubmit">
        <div>
            <label for="manHoursSelectId">Choose a time: </label>
            <select v-model="manHoursSelect" id="manHoursSelectId">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1">All day</option>
                <option value="2">Morning</option>
                <option value="3">Afternoon</option>
                <option value="4">Custom</option>
            </select>
            <span v-if="errors.manHoursSelect" class="text-red-500">
                {{ errors.manHoursSelect }}</span
            >
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="manHoursId">Select hours: </label>
            <select v-model="manHours" id="manHoursId" :disabled="assignManHours">
                <option v-for="hour in manHoursArr" :value="hour">
                    {{ hour }}
                </option>
            </select>
            <span v-if="errors.manHours" class="text-red-500">
                {{ errors.manHours }}</span
            >
        </div>
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
    import { toTypedSchema } from "@vee-validate/zod";
    import { useField, useForm } from "vee-validate";
    import * as z from "zod";

    const formSchema = toTypedSchema(
        z.object({
            manHoursSelect: z.string().min(1),
            manHours: z.string().min(1),
        })
    );

    const { handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
        validationSchema: formSchema,
        initialValues: {
            manHoursSelect: "",
            manHours: "",
        },
    });

    const { value: manHoursSelect } = useField("manHoursSelect");
    const { value: manHours } = useField("manHours");

    const onSubmit = handleSubmit((values) => {
        console.log("Form submitted values", values);
    });

    // Generate manhours arrays
    const range = (start: number, stop: number, step: number) => {
        return Array.from({ length: Math.ceil((stop - start) / step) }, (_, i) =>
            (start + i * step).toFixed(1)
        );
    };
    const manHoursArr = range(0, 1.1, 0.1);

    watch(manHoursSelect, (newValue) => {
        if (newValue === "1") {
            manHours.value = "1.0";
        } else if (newValue === "2" || newValue === "3") {
            manHours.value = "0.5";
        } else {
            manHours.value = "";
        }
    });

    const assignManHours = computed(() => {
        return manHoursSelect.value !== "4";
    });
</script>

However, I cannot recreate this using Shadcn-vue. The value logged in console for the 2nd select is correct, but visually it is not updating its value.
If I change the v-bind in the second select to use the variable manHours, then it will visually be correct, but then the value when submitted will be incorrect.
I think the answer lies in using v-bind or v-model correctly, but I can't figure it out. Here is my code using shadcn-vue.
<template>
    <form @submit="onSubmit">
        <FormField v-slot="{ field }" name="manHoursSelect">
            <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Man hours select</FormLabel>
                <Select v-bind="field">
                    <FormControl>
                        <SelectTrigger>
                            <SelectValue placeholder=""></SelectValue>
            </SelectTrigger>
                    </FormControl>
                    <SelectContent>
                        <SelectGroup>
                            <SelectItem value="1">1日</SelectItem>
                            <SelectItem value="2">午前</SelectItem>
                            <SelectItem value="3">午後</SelectItem>
                            <SelectItem value="4">入力</SelectItem>
                        </SelectGroup>
                    </SelectContent>
                </Select>
                <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
        </FormField>
        <br />
        <FormField v-slot="{ field }" name="manHours">
            <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Man hours select</FormLabel>
                    <Select v-bind="field" :disabled="assignManHours">
                        <FormControl>
                            <SelectTrigger>
                                <SelectValue placeholder=""></SelectValue>
                            </SelectTrigger>
                        </FormControl>
            <SelectContent>
                            <SelectGroup>
                                <SelectItem　v-for="hour in manHoursArr"　:key="hour"
                            :value="hour"
                >{{ hour }}</SelectItem>
                            </SelectGroup>
                        </SelectContent>
                    </Select>
                    <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
            </FormField>
            <br />
            <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
    </form>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
    import { toTypedSchema } from "@vee-validate/zod";
    import { useField, useForm } from "vee-validate";
    import * as z from "zod";

    const formSchema = toTypedSchema(
        z.object({
            manHoursSelect: z.string().min(1),
            manHours: z.string().min(1),
        })
    );

    const { handleSubmit } = useForm({
        validationSchema: formSchema,
        initialValues: {
            manHoursSelect: "",
            manHours: "",
        },
    });

    const { value: manHoursSelect } = useField("manHoursSelect");
    const { value: manHours } = useField("manHours");

    const onSubmit = handleSubmit((values) => {
        console.log("Form submitted values", values);
    });

    // Generate　manhours arrays
    const range = (start: number, stop: number, step: number) => {
        return Array.from({ length: Math.ceil((stop - start) / step) }, (_, i) =>
            (start + i * step).toFixed(1)
        );
    };
    const manHoursArr = range(0, 1.1, 0.1);

    watch(manHoursSelect, (newValue) => {
        if (newValue === "1") {
            manHours.value = "1.0";
        } else if (newValue === "2" || newValue === "3") {
            manHours.value = "0.5";
        } else {
            manHours.value = "";
        }
    });

    const assignManHours = computed(() => {
        return manHoursSelect.value !== "4";
    });
</script>

How can I make the value for the second select in the back match what is shown on the front?
